# converting dates and times with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, datetime, list-comprehension

I have a whole bunch of data and there are two lists consisting of dates and times that look as such:

dates: year-month-day

times: hour:minute:second

so I take them appart and put each into a separate list:

```
year,month,day = [i.split("-")[0] for i in date], [i.split("-")[1] for i in date], [i.split("-")[2] for i in date]
hour,minute,second = [i.split(":")[0] for i in time], [i.split(":")[1] for i in time], [i.split(":")[2] for i in time]
```

now I since each of these are long lists of the same length, I want to convert them into one list that contains them as `datetime` objects. So I used another list comprehension for this:

```
datetime_column = [datetime.datetime(int(y),int(m),int(d),int(h),int(m),int(s)) for y,m,d,h,m,s in year,month,day,hour,minute,second]
```

this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I know that this is because it is trying to iterate y,m,d,h,m and s through each list rather than just pair them up such as y with year, m with month, and so on. So here is my question:

**How can you use list comprehension with 6 variables each going through 1 of 6 separate lists? And if it is not possible, what would be an efficient way to do the equivalent?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making things too complicated for yourself. Zip the `date` and `time` lists, then use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
datetime_column = [datetime.datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(d, t),
                                              '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                   for d, t in zip(date, time)]
```

`zip()` pairs up each `date` string with each `time` string, then we use each pair to create a full timestamp string, to be parsed by the `strptime()` method.

Comment: that worked perfectly! one quick question...per say this was not for datetime objects and I wanted to do something like I said with list comprehension. Maybe I wrote a function that takes 6 inputs and I want to create a list with instances of it...is that possible?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: You are looping over each individual component list there; the first element in the loop is the `year` list, then the `month` list, etc, where you try to unpack each of those lists to 6 variables. You wanted to use `zip()` there too.

Comment: Ah so zip all of those together so it's one thing! So if I were to use my old method except with `zip(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)` it would work?

Answer (score 0):

Although there are better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, here's an answer to the question you actually asked:

```
datetime_column = [
    datetime.datetime(
        int(dt[0]),int(dt[1]),int(dt[2]),int(dt[3]),int(dt[4]),int(dt[5]))
            for dt in zip(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)]
```

or more succinctly:

```
datetime_column = [
    datetime.datetime(*dt) for dt in
            (map(int, v) for v in zip(year,month,day,hour,minute,second))]
```